# how to submit sitemaps using seach console api when the domain is in the form sc-domain:xxx.com

Tags: python, google-api, google-search-console

When I use the google search console sitemap submission api (documented here: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sitemaps/submit) for submitting sitemaps, I tried these 3 variants:

- sc-example.com
- https://example.com
- http://example.com

unfortunately, when I run it I get this error message:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "User does not have sufficient permission for site 'http://XXXXX.com/'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "User does not have sufficient permission for site 'http://XXXXX.com/'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999."
 }
}
```

for http and https, these variants don't work, for sc-domain: it fails even worse.

even though *I'm authorized* to the whole domain, for some reason, I'm not authorized to post a sitemap??? for the domain I'm authorized? this doesn't make sense.

On the other hand, Getting list of sitemaps, for sites with http and https it works, but for sc-domains it fails.

I tried interactively in the console, no help.
https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sitemaps/submit?apix_params=%7B%22siteUrl%22%3A%22xxxx.com%22%2C%22feedpath%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.com%2Fxxxx.xml%22%7D

Environment details

- OS: OSX
- Python version: Python 3.6.5
- pip version: pip 19.3.1
- `google-api-python-client` version: (1.7.11) (from PIP)

Steps to reproduce

1. run this code (as per the example provided):

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('webmasters', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

service.sitemaps().submit(siteUrl="sc-domain:example.com",feedpath="http://example.com/sitemap.xml").execute()
```

2. unfortunately, I'm getting this result:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/sc-domain%XXXXX.com/sitemaps/https%3A%2F%XXXXX.com%2Fsomefile.xml? returned "">
```

`<returned "">`
is totally not a very useful error message at all.

after fiddling with the object, I got this:

```
>>> error.content
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

I have to say it's a rather cryptic error message, I don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance for this.

I asked the guys at google https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/820 but who knows if they even read these messages...